# Unknown logical error while using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, email-spam

I'm working on an Email Spam Classifier model, I've used Tkinter to build the GUI and I successfully have and also added functionality to the button to classify the given text. And on running it no error is thrown. But the model doesn't classify the text as spam and ham, whatever the input text maybe the prediction is always spam, it would be of great help if any of you could help me.

Code for my model (with fuctionality to button):

```
data=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Python\\Spyder\\Email spam Classifier\\spam.csv", 
encoding='latin-1')
data['Category']=data['Category'].map({'ham':0, 'spam':1})

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
corpus = []

for i in range(0, len(data)):
    review = re.sub('[^a-zA-z]', ' ', data['Message'][i])
    review = review.lower()
    review = review.split()

    review = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in review if not word in 
    stopwords.words('english')]
    review = ' '.join(review)
    corpus.append(review)


cv = CountVectorizer()
X = cv.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()

y = pd.get_dummies((data['Category']))
y = y.iloc[:,1].values


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 0)

Spam_clasfcn_model = MultinomialNB(alpha=.01)
Spam_clasfcn_model.partial_fit(X_train, y_train, classes=np.unique(y_train))
y_pred = Spam_clasfcn_model.predict(X_test)

def classify():
lab = ['not spam', 'spam']
x = cv.transform([spam.get()]).toarray()
p = Spam_clasfcn_model.predict(x)
s = [str(i) for i in p]
a = int("".join(s))
res = str("This is " + lab[a])

if lab[a]=='spam':

    classification = Label(root, text=res, font=('helvetica', 15 , 'bold'), fg="red")
    classification.pack()
else:
    classification = Label(root, text=res, font=('helvetica', 15, 'bold'), fg="green")
    classification.pack()
```

Code for my GUI:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x200')
root.maxsize(500,200)
root.minsize(500,200)
root.title('SPAM EMAIL CLASSIFIER')
root['bg'] = "grey15"

title = Label(root, text="SPAM EMAIL CLASSIFIER", 
               font=('agencyFB',15,'bold'),fg="black")
title.place(x=90,y=5)

Label(root, text="Enter Mail to Classify", 
      font=('agencyFB',10,'bold'), fg="black").place(x=50,y=50)

spam = Entry(root, width=50, bg="white", relief=GROOVE, 
              borderwidth=2, border=2)
spam.place(x=50,y=80)

button = Button(root,text="Predict",
                    font=('agencyFB',8,'bold'),bg="grey",fg="white", 
                    command=classify)
button.place(x=360,y=78)
root.mainloop()
```

Modules and packages used:

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk    
import re 
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is somewhere inside the AI's prediction/training. Have you tested just the model to check if it's working? What are the outputs of the model? From what I can see you are just concatenating the output the of model and then indexing `["not spam", "spam"]` with the result.

Comment: I've tried that, it works like a charm. For e.g., if I type in, "Hello good morning", it displays, "It's not a spam" and if "Spin the wheel to collect rewards" is typed, it exactly displays, "It is a spam".

Comment: What are the raw outputs of the model? What shape is the output? I think something is wrong there. Also are you sure it's `["not spam", "spam"]` and not `["spam", "not spam"]`? I can't see anything wrong with your `tkinter` code so I am assuming the error is somewhere else